# NetInstall Windows/Linux/Other from OS X Server

Tags: mac-osx-server, disk-image, netboot, netinstall

Just recently added OS X Server to my work Mac Pro, and found the NetInstall suite of tools... And I love it!

But after setting up El Capitan for Boot/Install/Restore... I want more:  Is it possible to create NetBoot/NetInstall/NetRestore images of Mac-Supported Windows or Linux? I.E. Windows 10, Windows 7, Debian, Ubuntu, etc. I have El Capitan and Yosemite Installers but it only detects the El Capitan for System Image Utility.

It would be awesome to give our Mac users the option to boot to Windows without needing to re-partition, as well as facilitate Boot Camp installs of Windows and/or Linux (For our programmers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NetInstall service only (directly) supports OS X network images. It can serve multiple versions (El Capitan, Yosemite, Mavericks, whatever), but you must create the images under the same major version as the image you're creating. So if you want a Yosemite image, you need to copy the Yosemite installer to a Mac running Yosemite, and run the Yosemite version of System Image Utility. Once the image (actually, the entire .nbi folder) is created, copy it to whatever version of OS X Server you're running, drop it in /Library/NetBoot/NetBootSP0, and it'll be available in the Server.app interface.

While NetInstall doesn't support Windows ( or Linux images, there's a free third-party package, [DeployStudio](http://www.deploystudio.com) that supports them (as well as OS X images). DeployStudio is more flexible and powerful than the basic NetInstall service, but it's also more complex to set up. You'll need:

- An AFP, SMB, or NFS file server sharing a "Repository" folder that'll contain the master images, installer packages, scripts, etc.
- A Mac running the DeployStudio server daemon. This does a number of things, but the most important is to tell clients how to mount the Repository.
- A DeployStudio NetBoot set. This is a NetBoot image (.nbi) that you'll serve from your NetInstall server, which boots clients into a "DeployStudio Runtime" environment. The Runtime will connect to the DeployStudio server, mount the Repository, and let you run whatever deployment workflows (imaging/updating/configuring/whatever processes) you have set up.

There are also a couple of setup/config tools:

- DeployStudio Assistant should be run on the same computer as the DeployStudio daemon; it does initial setup stuff, like configuring the Repository and creating the NetBoot set.
- DeployStudio Admin is the tool for ongoing admin, such as managing workflows.

I recommend using the "Full Network" setup in the [quick install guide](http://www.deploystudio.com/documentation/quick-install-guide), then experimenting from there. Once you get all the pieces set up and talking to each other properly, it's pretty slick.

I haven't used it for Windows or Linux images, but my understanding is you'd use [WinClone](http://twocanoes.com/products/mac/winclone) and `dd` respectively to create the images for them.